# How do we identify suffixes?

Tags: nouns

My question is, how to categorize words as a noun, adjective, verb or adverb on the basis of  suffix. Are there any common endings specific to these parts of speech?

For example-

> Kingdom (N)
>
> Wisdom (N)
>
> Extensive (Adj)
>
> Wooden (Adj)

If yes, what about this example? Is *-en* an exception?

Words ending with -en

> Brighten (V)
>
> Soften (V)
>
> Wooden (Adj)

I read few articles about suffix and its implications, but unfortunately, I did not find a convincing explanation.

Comment: This question is simply Too Broad. See [this Wiktionary page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-en) giving ***six*** different etymologies for the **-en** suffix. Doubtless some other suffixes actually have even more, so it's really not meaningful to single out that particular one.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No. Unlike many other languages, English does not use suffixes to identify parts of speech.

The only exception is that -ly usually indicates an adverb. "Happily", "quickly", "carefully", etc are all adverbs. Even that isn't 100%: "sprightly" is an adjective, and "well" is a very commonly-used adverb.

Sure, you can find some suffixes usually associated with one part of speech. Like "-er" is usually a noun, used to turn a verb into a noun. (Example: "Pay", to give someone money or other compensation. "Payer", one who pays.) But these are a tiny fraction of all nouns. You'd have to learn a very large set of such suffixes, and you'd still only be identifying a fraction of all words.

Sorry, but in English you pretty much have to learn the part of speech of each word, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

http://grammar.about.com/od/words/a/comsuffixes.htm

The suffix -en
has two uses. You can  add it to a noun for a substance to get an adjective:

wood wooden, gold golden.

and you can add it to adjectives to form verbs:

short to shorten, long to lengthen, bright to brighten, hard  to harden, soft to soften.

On the Internet you should find lists of suffixes for nouns, adjectives and verbs.

A small list is given in about.com, see above.